# Angular adding single quotes and variable to the component.html not reading the variable and quotes

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular13

I am using Angular 13 and in my component.html I have this:

This line works:

```
<highcharts-chart [constructorType]="'stockChart'"></highcharts-chart>
```

Now, when I have a variable:

```
myvalue = 'stockChart';
```

And do this:

```
<highcharts-chart [constructorType]="myvalue"></highcharts-chart>
```

or

```
<highcharts-chart [constructorType]="'myvalue'"></highcharts-chart>
```

or

```
<highcharts-chart [constructorType]="{{myvalue}}"></highcharts-chart>
```

The 3 above don't work but the first one does.

How can I get it to work using the variable?

Comment: `<highcharts-chart [constructorType]="myvalue"></highcharts-chart>` is a valid syntax. Could you do a live example of this problem with the library you're using?

Comment: First one from the section of 3 is valid as @JacopoSciampi pointed out.

Comment: Hi @deszok, Using `[constructorType]="myvalue"` works perfectly fine. Please check this live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-p44v1a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try escape characters in component.ts  and bind that value in html

[image]